# After creating an embedding layer using a tensorflow placeholder, how is the tf.nn.embedding_lookup() function used with it?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, word-embedding

I'm trying to add a pre-trained word2vec word embedding to my tensorflow code. Now after creating the embedding matrix, one way to add this layer is by creating a tensorflow variable, but this leads to repetition of calculation and hence, not efficient. 
The other way is to create a placeholder and pass data through that.

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[vsize, 200]),
                trainable=False, name="W")
embedding_init = W.assign(self._embedding)
#self._embedding is the placeholder

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(embedding_init,feed_dict={self._embedding:emb_matrix})
```

Now I want to be able to pass data to that embedding by calling the tf.nn.embedding_lookup() function, what tensor exactly do I pass into the lookup function?

```
tf.nn.embedding_lookup(?,list(word2id),input_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W,input_data)
```